# How do I remove the scrollbar from this IFRAME code?

Tags: iframe, scrollbar, giphy

I wanted to embed a gif through giphy on the sidebar of my site, but it appears with scrollbars, which I want to get rid off. Can you please help?

Heres how it looks like (top right): https://www.cinemarvellous.com/

Here's the code:

```
<iframe src="https://giphy.com/embed/QxH7OHwznjUMBeq2Lc" width="218" height="93" frameborder="0" class="giphy-embed"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Add Css for iframe  as below:

```
<style>
//Chrome, Safari, Opera

    .iframe ::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }  

    //Firefox
    .iframe { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; }

    //Internet Explorer

    .iframe { -ms-overflow-style: none; }

</style>
```